Writing lots of ANSI colored characters to the Console Screen Buffer is Slow
I am developing a 3D Console Application for fun and I have been using the basic Win32 Colors for a while but I wanted to upgrade to full color spectrum using ANSI. I have got color working, but the process is very expensive. There are about 20,000 characters drawn the to screen every frame, and in order to give them color, I am surrounding them with the ANSI color sequence\033[38;2;<r\>;<g\>;<b\>;m and \x1b[0m. This means that the character buffer I am writing to is ~20,000 * 23 wide chars long. This obviously slows things to a crawl, so I am looking for smarter ways to give every character the full range of color.
I have thought about grouping characters with the same color and using a single ANSI sequence for those but I don't think that would create much of a performance increase because there will be lots of varying colors throughout the screen due to the lighting system I have.

Are you using the legacy or are you using the newer, more performant Windows Terminal?

@Boofhead I'm on Windows 10, so I'm pretty sure its legacy.

Installing Windows Terminal takes just a few seconds. Btw, rewriting the whole screen every frame is probably still too expensive. You could use PDCurses to make the drawing a bit more optimized.

Trying to optimize for throughput is only meaningful if you're bandwidth-limited. I doubt that is the case. You'll have to measure if you want to know.

@Boofhead does that not require the user to select how the application is run, or can you force a runtime environment in the application itself?  AFAIK, from the application point-of-view it is just a console.  Using the console API directly rather than through the ANSI layer would clearly be more efficient as there is then no need to parse the ANSI strings, or pass through the intermediate stdio layer.

If you grouped by colour, you will then have to set the X,Y position for each non consecutive character and will gain nothing.  I doubt there is any way to make this fast enough when the bottleneck is the ANSI driver which you cannot "optimise".  It is probably not so much the screen I/O that is the issue than just the load of run-time parsing of strings.

This is why no-one writes anything serious in console mode. You should learn how to draw in graphics mode, either directly using Win32 GDI API or using frameworks like SFML, SDL2, Qt, etc.

@rustyx Not sure what constitutes "serious" to you but some folks have pulled off some nice demos in text mode. It ultimately boils down to the capabilities of the console host, and the determination of a single developer to convince the people in charge of the Windows Terminal that it doesn't actually take a PhD to make it fast.

Whether you have set the console to the Virtual Terminal mode. You could try to use SetConsoleMode function with 'ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING'.
